# Collection Was Modified; Enumeration Operation May Not Continue

Tags: vb.net

I ran this code and the Error came out:
Collection Was Modified; Enumeration Operation May Not Execute.
It also highlighted this line:

```
Next
```

Here's the code:

```
Dim Maxnum As Integer = 100
        Dim PrimeList As New Generic.List(Of Integer)
        PrimeList.Add(2)


        For Prime As Integer = 3 To Maxnum Step 1
            For Each element As String In PrimeList
                If Prime Mod element = 0 Then

                Else
                    PrimeList.Add(Prime)
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Would anyone like to help me, please?

Great thanks!

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  `For Each element As String In PrimeList` makes no sense for a `List(Of Int32)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search, you will find other ways of checking for prime numbers, but your method is fine if you just want to find the primes between 2 and 100.

If you are going to loop through all the elements in PrimeList, you need to avoid updating Primelist inside the loop. In any case, you can't decide that a number is prime until you have checked all the possible divisors.

The following code uses a `Boolean` to keep track if any divisors were found.

```
Dim Maxnum As Integer = 100
Dim PrimeList As New Generic.List(Of Integer)
PrimeList.Add(2)

For Prime As Integer = 3 To Maxnum Step 1
    Dim isPrime As Boolean = True
    For Each element As String In PrimeList
        If Prime Mod element = 0 Then isPrime = False
    Next
    If isPrime Then PrimeList.Add(Prime)
Next
```

Comment: I know it may sound stupid but what is `For Each element As String In PrimeList` for in getting the prime numbers? I mean why check again the whole list if you are already iterating up to 100 then just Mod it to 2? Sorry didn't had my coffee today, just being dumb.

Comment: @CrushSundae As I suggested, there are more efficient ways of finding prime numbers (at least if you are dealing with very large numbers). In this answer, I concentrated on the problem the OP was having with his chosen method. The purpose of the inner loop is to only check if the number is divisible by one of the lower prime numbers, there is no need to check whether it is divisible by a non-prime number (as the non-prime number must be divisible by some other prime number).

Comment: Enlightened. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just as the error states, you are modifying the collection while iterating it.  When you call PrimeList.Add(Prime) it adds another item to the collections thus changing the length.

```
        For Each element As String In PrimeList
            If Prime Mod element = 0 Then

            Else
                PrimeList.Add(Prime)
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: That code will throw the same exception as you are modifying PrimeList.

Comment: @Blackwood that code is what the OP posted.  I was trying to explain what he had done wrong.